# How to specify py2app icon?

Tags: python, macos, py2app

How do I specify the icon file when using py2app?

Just now I create the setup file:

```
py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py
```

and then build the application bundle:

```
 python setup.py py2app -A
```

where is it that I specify the icon file.. getting a little confused. Thanks for any help.

according to this link- http://packages.python.org/py2app/options.html,  I should add it as an option.

Currently my setup.py file looks like this:

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['hello.py']
DATA_FILES = ['chalkboard.jpg']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True,
'iconfile': '/Users/grahamethomson/Documents/College/HND/oop/game/personal       developoment/G/icon.icns'}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Answer (score 26):

In your setup.py, add iconfile

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {
    'iconfile':'icon.icns',
    'plist': {'CFBundleShortVersionString':'0.1.0',}
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    name='MacApp',
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: Thank you. Full documentation here: http://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html

Answer (score 9):

Answering my own question.

To add an icon file simply add the iconfile option when creating setup.py:

```
py2applet --make-setup foo.py --iconfile images/icon.icns
```

Note: You must not leave the `icon.icns` under the same folder as your main script `foo.py`. It must be placed under a subfolder like `images/`, otherwise you'd end up with `DATA_FILE=['--iconfile']` in your `setup.py`, which would fail because that's not a data file.

Comment: make sure the icon you are using is compatible - editing the extension of the file will not achieve this. Download a convertor such as http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/18369/img2icns

Answer (score 1):

These solutions didn't work for me on python3. The --iconfile switch was throwing errors about not finding the file. In fact the switch is not even needed. This worked for me.

```
py2applet --make-setup MyApplication.py myicon.icns
python3 setup.py py2app
```

Just put the icon in the same folder as the source code and this does what you want. Found in [py2applet help](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py2applet.html?highlight=icon#py2applet).