# Python - TkInter Icon & GUI

Tags: user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

I've been starting to learn python recently and have spent several hours trying to find a way to set a custom icon for the application however all the results that I find are either outdated or incompatible with Mac. Is there a working example for all platforms that I can use? A custom GUI is not on the top of priorities but if there is a documentation that I haven't found I would be very grateful if someone could show me.

Edit:

Just a quick summary of Jonah very kindly provided:

1. Download get-pip.py [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py)
2. Run get-pip.py from terminal using: "python get-pip.py"
3. Install py2app with: "pip install -U py2app"

   **Note!**

   This may not apply to everyone but I have to use: "pip3 install -U py2app"
4. Use and download configuration similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608080/how-to-specify-py2app-icon)
5. Convert your file to a .icns at this [site](https://iconverticons.com/online/)
6. Set the filepaths in the setup.py according to your .py script and your icns image.
7. Run the setup.py with: "python setup.py py2app"
8. Locate your app in the dist folder that was created :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So to add an icon from memory you have to make a .icns file. Follow [these](http://applehelpwriter.com/2012/12/16/make-your-own-icns-icons-for-free/) or [these](http://applehelpwriter.com/2013/07/22/automator-make-your-own-icons/) instructions. Secondly you have to make the program into an app. To do this follow the instructions [here](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) but don't do it yet. Ok now go into setup.py and add under options `'iconfile' : 'icon.icns'`. Create the app now. It will only work if you put the icns image in the same folder as setup.py. This will add both a icon to the app and the top corner where the Tkinter logo shows on Windows.

Comment: @Pig Also go [here](http://pythonqanda.weebly.com) to contact me via email. I can then give further help!

Comment: Sorry D: having issues installing py2app and I don't know how to accept the answer.

Comment: @pig What is the problem?

Comment: @pigman To install pip read the instructions [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/installing/). Then go pip install py2app. After that py2app is installed and you just need to create your setup.py file according to [this](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) documentation, and then run py2app setup.py.

Comment: Update! Thank you very very much for your help! Everything works now :)