# Changing icon of .app makes it crash (OSX)

Tags: macos

So I've created a program in python and I have converted it to an executable (.app extension) which runs perfectly.

Now I want to change the icon the .app to make it look nicer on the desktop, but whenever I change the icon and run it, it says "you cant open the application because it may be damaged or incomplete". Can someone please help me with changing the icon without corrupting the file, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your app is codesigned. Changing the icon invalidates the code signature.

Whatever process you're using to bundle up your program into an .app will need to be updated to set the icon at that point.

If you're using py2app, [here's an old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608080/how-to-specify-py2app-icon) that documents how to set the icon.